# Will booting from a USB erase my current OS?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, bootable-media

That is all I want to know. I have created a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu installed on it. Will it affect my Windows 7 at all?

Comment: You asked two different questions... oh well. What it does depends on what is on the USB stick.  A standard Ubuntu live demo will not normally erase windows, unless you tell it to or enter malicious/careless commands from root(admin).  Most standard Ubuntu live demos have a web browser and maybe openoffice that you can play with to decide whether to do a permanent install (e.g. check that the mouse, screen, keyboard, speakers really work) but do not start servers or other backdoors.  However, if you find a stick in the parking lot or get one from an evil genius friend all bets are off.

Answer (score 3):

Should not affect your Windows 7.  Your computer will boot from the USB instead.  You can potentially affect your Windows 7 if you access the partition with your Windows 7 when using Ubuntu and mess around with it.